# Java regex skipping matches

Tags: java, regex

I have some text; I want to extract pairs of words that are not separated by punctuation. This is the code:

```
//n-grams
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[a-z]+");
if (n == 2) {
    p = Pattern.compile("[a-z]+ [a-z]+");
}
if (n == 3) {
    p = Pattern.compile("[a-z]+ [a-z]+ [a-z]+");
}
Matcher m = p.matcher(text.toLowerCase());
ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

while (m.find()) {
    String temporary = m.group();
    System.out.println(temporary);

    result.add(temporary);
}
```

The problem is that it skips some matches. For example

> "My name is James"

, for n = 3, must match

> "my name is" and "name is james"

, but instead it matches just the first. Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can capture it using groups in lookahead

```
(?=(\b[a-z]+\b \b[a-z]+\b \b[a-z]+\b))
```

This causes it to capture in two groups..So in your case it would be

Group1->`my name is`

Group2->`name is james`

Answer (score 1):

In regular expression pattern defined by regex is applied on the String from left to right and once a source character is used in a match, it can’t be reused.

For example, regex “121″ will match “31212142121″ only twice as “*121*___121″.

Comment: Is there a way to overcome this?

Comment: No.you can match it by capturing it in `group` using `lookahead` like this `(?=(121))`

Comment: I am not aware of any way we can reuse the used cells. You can try split() method to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use the argument to the `find()` method of `Matcher`:

```
Matcher m = p.matcher(text);
int position = 0;
while (m.find(position)) { 
  String temporary = m.group();
  position = m.start();  
  System.out.println(position + ":" + temporary);
  position++;
}
```

So after each iteration, it searches again based on the last start index.

Hope that helped!

Comment: This matches "name is bond", "ame is bond", "me is bond"... :)

Comment: Oh! Right! I was thinking on another type of regex, like searching for a string like `aba` in a string like `abababa`. Doing _my way_ resolves the issue and find all occurrences. Sorry for the misunderstanding! Yours require another approach for sure.