# Getting overlapping matches with multiple patterns in Java regex

Tags: java, regex

I have the same problem as in [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18751486/matching-one-string-multiple-times-using-regex-in-java)

but with multiple patterns. My regex is like:

```
Pattern word = Pattern.compile("([\w]+ [\d]+)|([\d]+ suite)|([\w]+ road)");
```

If my sample text is,

> XYZ Road 123 Suite

My desire output is,

> XYZ Road 123
>
> 123 suite

But am getting

> XYZ Road 123

only.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: could you explain your needs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try the below regex which uses positive lookahead assertion.

```
(?=(\b\w+ Road \d+\b)|(\b\d+ suite\b))
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dU7oN5/17)

```
String s = "XYZ Road 123 Suite";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("(?i)(?=(\\b\\w+ Road \\d+\\b)|(\\b\\d+ suite))").matcher(s);
while(m.find())
{
    if(m.group(1) != null) System.out.println(m.group(1));
    if(m.group(2) != null) System.out.println(m.group(2));
}
```

**Output:**

```
XYZ Road 123
123 Suite
```

Comment: If I have some 15k groups, may i need to add 15k if blocks?

Comment: In the above example I have 2 groups ie., 2 regex patterns to match. So as you specified I can get the matched text using m.group(1), m.group(2). Similarly If I have 15k groups(regex patterns) what I need to do?

Comment: then it's better to use a for loop.

Answer (score 1):

```
(?=(\b[\w]+ [\d]+))|(?=(\b[\d]+ suite))|(?=(\b[\w]+ road))
```

Try this.See demo.Grab the captures.

https://regex101.com/r/dU7oN5/16

Use `positive lookahead` to avoid string being consumed.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this, maybe?

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([\\w ] Road) (\\d+) (Suite)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);
if(m.find) {
   System.out.println(m.group(1) + " " + m.group(2));
   System.out.println(m.group(2) + " " + m.group(3));
}
```