# Regular expression to match all path in the tree

Tags: python, regex

I have a folder tree like `/country/province/city/home` that I want to get all sub-paths in it:

- `/country`
- `/country/province`
- `/country/province/city`
- `/country/province/city/home`

I can use pattern `(?<=/)[\w]*` to get all the words and then join them one by one with `'/'.join()`. But is there any way to achieve all the sub-paths with one regex ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14798220/how-can-i-search-sub-folders-using-glob-glob-module-in-python might answer your question.

Comment: Use [os.path.split](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.split)

Comment: can't be done with basic regex (a certain part of the string can only be part of one match) but lookahead might work http://stackoverflow.com/a/18751542/412529

Comment: While it is possible to get overlapping matches by placing a capturing group inside a lookahead, each match must still start from a different position.

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

for root, dirs, files in os.walk("."):
      print root
```

It prints

```
/country
/country/province
/country/province/city
/country/province/city/home
```

Comment: This approach only works when the path is exist. But what I have is a string of path that I'm going to create. That's why I need regex

Answer (score 1):

```
x="/country/province/city/home"
y= re.split(r"(?<=[^/])\/",x)
str=y[0]
print str
for x in y[1:]:
    str=str+"/"+x
    print str
```

Try this.

Comment: @dragon2fly see here https://regex101.com/r/sH8aR8/20 Once you split by this you have a list which we just loop thrugh and club together.

Comment: so there is no direct way to get all subpaths at once? your `for loop` is another way of `'/'.join(x[:index])` of me

Comment: @dragon2fly yes you are right.I dont know if it can be done via some module.